# Proper nuclear fission simulation in C++

Tags: c++, statistics, simulation, physics

I'm trying to simulate atomic fission in C++.

Fissile nuclides have known probabilities to produce certain atomic numbers and mass numbers as fission products, such distributions are called fission products yield.

I know mass product and atomic product fission yields of uranium-235 (available [here](https://wwwndc.jaea.go.jp/cgi-bin/FPYfig)).

A fission product yield distribution adds up to 2, since a nuclear fission produces 2 new nuclides and 2 or 3 free neutrons.

While I may have misunderstood some physics concept, from a computer science point of view my problem is to generate 5 integers with known probability distributions, in pseudocode:

```
massYield = [...]
possibleMassProducts = [...]
atomicYield = [...]
possibleAtomicProducts = [...]
firstProductMassNumber = generateRandom(massYield, possibleMassProducts)
firstProductAtomicNumber = generateRandom(atomicYield, possibleAtomicProducts)
secondProductMassNumber = generateRandom(massYield, possibleMassProducts)
secondProductAtomicNumber = generateRandom(atomicYield, possibleAtomicProducts)
freeNeutrons = generateRandom([0.5, 0.5], [2, 3])
```

I've made a class called IntegerRandomGenerator which generates random numbers following a specific distribution:

```
class IntegerRandomGenerator
{
public:
    IntegerRandomGenerator(std::vector<double> distribution, std::vector<int> values)
    {
        size_t size_dist = distribution.size();
        size_t size_val  = values.size();
        if( size_dist != size_val )
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("distribution and values vectors shall have the same length");
        }
        else
        {
            for( double p_i : distribution )
            {
                mDist.push_back(p_i);
            }
            for( int x_i : values )
            {
                mValues.push_back(x_i);
            }
        }
    }


    int generate();

private:
    std::vector<double> mDist;
    std::vector<int>   mValues;
    std::mt19937_64 mRng;
};

int IntegerRandomGenerator::generate()
{
    uint64_t timeSeed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

    std::seed_seq ss{uint32_t(timeSeed & 0xffffffff), uint32_t(timeSeed>>32)};
    mRng.seed(ss);

    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0,1);
    double random = unif(mRng);

    uint32_t distSize = static_cast<uint32_t>(mDist.size());
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < distSize; i++)
    {
        if(random < mDist.at(i))
        {
            return mValues.at(i);
        }
        else
        {
            random -= mDist.at(i);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Hence my strategy to generate fission products is the following:

```
std::vector<int> generateFissionValues(std::vector<double> aYields, std::vector<double> zYields, std::vector<int> aNumbers, std::vector<int> zNumbers)
{
    std::vector<double> massNormalized, atomicNormalized;
    std::vector<double> unif;
    std::vector<int> nNumbers;

    for(double p_i : aYields)
    {
        massNormalized.push_back(p_i/2);
    }

    for(double q_i : zYields)
    {
        atomicNormalized.push_back(q_i/2);
    }

    unif.push_back(0.5);
    unif.push_back(0.5);
    nNumbers.push_back(2);
    nNumbers.push_back(3);

    IntegerRandomGenerator massGenerator(massNormalized, aNumbers);
    IntegerRandomGenerator atomGenerator(atomicNormalized, zNumbers);
    IntegerRandomGenerator freeGenerator(unif, nNumbers);

    int a_Product1 = massGenerator.generate();
    int z_Product1 = atomGenerator.generate();

    int a_Product2 = massGenerator.generate();
    int z_Product2 = atomGenerator.generate();

    int freeNeutr = freeGenerator.generate();

    std::vector<int> fissionProducts;

    fissionProducts.push_back(a_Product1);
    fissionProducts.push_back(z_Product1);

    fissionProducts.push_back(a_Product2);
    fissionProducts.push_back(z_Product2);

    fissionProducts.push_back(freeNeutr);

    return fissionProducts;
}
```

What I expect to get, repeating this routine a fixed number of times and counting occurrencies of each atomic and mass number, is to get an empirical distribution which is similar to the theoretically known.
This is my main:

```
#define MIN_MASS_NUMBER 66
#define MIN_ATOMIC_NUMBER 23
#define MASS_YIELD_LENGTH 107
#define ATOMIC_YIELD_LENGTH 49

double MASS_YIELD[]=
{
        7.2405671e-10,  3.6155178e-09,  8.3798843e-09,  1.4793428e-08,  3.7126096e-08,  8.4074658e-08,  2.6566021e-07,
        1.0675927e-06,  3.3943611e-06,  1.0705677e-05,  3.0947722e-05,  7.5980282e-05,  2.0984921e-04,  4.4786922e-04,
        1.2829461e-03,  1.9049358e-03,  3.2662529e-03,  5.3619387e-03,  8.9643421e-03,  1.2891416e-02,  1.4066064e-02,
        2.5282028e-02,  3.4205412e-02,  4.7612426e-02,  5.8969791e-02,  5.8718196e-02,  5.9912701e-02,  6.2513918e-02,
        6.5931230e-02,  6.5585160e-02,  6.3729133e-02,  6.1194661e-02,  5.7681295e-02,  6.1623490e-02,  6.5885448e-02,
        5.1864512e-02,  4.2059644e-02,  3.0389326e-02,  1.8792336e-02,  9.7353401e-03,  4.0277579e-03,  1.4658471e-03,
        5.4222280e-04,  3.1255579e-04,  2.5608411e-04,  1.7477930e-04,  1.3934770e-04,  1.3765549e-04,  1.1957731e-04,
        1.3077006e-04,  1.3324824e-04,  1.1755897e-04,  1.1374826e-04,  1.2290949e-04,  1.2642393e-04,  1.3080367e-04,
        1.5523846e-04,  1.1021012e-04,  2.6858588e-04,  2.9061019e-04,  5.8370361e-04,  1.5268885e-03,  3.4896815e-03,
        5.3614445e-03,  1.8159164e-02,  2.8895004e-02,  4.3250233e-02,  6.7141993e-02,  7.8703816e-02,  6.5640320e-02,
        6.1137911e-02,  6.3605380e-02,  6.7934012e-02,  6.4934315e-02,  6.2395971e-02,  5.8687079e-02,  5.8447475e-02,
        5.9831620e-02,  5.5176036e-02,  3.9532454e-02,  3.0059773e-02,  2.2527624e-02,  1.6771722e-02,  1.0853545e-02,
        6.5508342e-03,  4.1317995e-03,  2.6763110e-03,  1.5870986e-03,  7.4634286e-04,  3.2221285e-04,  1.4892861e-04,
        6.1673994e-05,  3.2940204e-05,  1.0121245e-05,  3.1986347e-06,  8.5523451e-07,  1.5949051e-07,  6.1183839e-08,
        1.8867389e-08,  9.5405554e-09,  3.6338899e-09,  2.4780248e-09,  5.7277553e-10,  2.3914282e-10,  5.0200588e-11,
        2.3540988e-11,  7.7074464e-12
};

double ATOMIC_YIELD[]=
{
        2.0558300e-19,  2.8862345e-14,  1.3368750e-11,  1.6193162e-09,  1.3709663e-08,  3.0150265e-07,  3.6301782e-06,  
        1.1200954e-04,  7.0351909e-04,  4.4498299e-03,  9.1719425e-03,  3.6528367e-02,  5.2682609e-02,  1.5625724e-01,  
        1.2071735e-01,  1.9331319e-01,  1.2675553e-01,  1.8037105e-01,  6.8939851e-02,  4.3268378e-02,  3.4683702e-03,  
        4.1462569e-04,  2.2779437e-04,  3.4012286e-04,  2.7543142e-04,  1.6063619e-03,  1.7210332e-03,  3.6208508e-02,  
        7.7033688e-02,  1.7331044e-01,  1.1582092e-01,  2.0090419e-01,  1.1037331e-01,  1.6401242e-01,  6.0615264e-02,  
        4.1834320e-02,  1.3435892e-02,  4.5405310e-03,  4.6638638e-04,  1.0987593e-04,  5.1296865e-06,  3.9564637e-07,  
        1.1679425e-08,  1.9805406e-09,  7.0990343e-11,  4.8416648e-12,  2.4283831e-14,  2.4747259e-17,  0.0000000e+00
};

int main()
{
    const int nSim = 10000;

    std::vector<double> distMass(std::begin(MASS_YIELD), std::end(MASS_YIELD));
    std::vector<double> distAtom(std::begin(ATOMIC_YIELD), std::end(ATOMIC_YIELD));
    std::vector<int>   massNumbers;
    std::vector<int>   atomNumbers;

    for(int i = 0; i < MASS_YIELD_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        massNumbers.push_back(i + MIN_MASS_NUMBER);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < ATOMIC_YIELD_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        atomNumbers.push_back(i + MIN_ATOMIC_NUMBER);
    }

    int countsPerZ[ATOMIC_YIELD_LENGTH];
    std::vector<double> relCountsPerZ;

    int countsPerA[MASS_YIELD_LENGTH];
    std::vector<double> relCountsPerA;

    memset(countsPerZ, 0x00, ATOMIC_YIELD_LENGTH * sizeof(int));
    memset(countsPerA, 0x00, MASS_YIELD_LENGTH * sizeof(int));

    std::cout << "Start " << nSim << " atomic fission simulations . . ." << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < nSim;)
    {
        std::vector<int> fissionProducts = generateFissionValues(distMass, distAtom, massNumbers, atomNumbers);

        int a1 = fissionProducts.at(0);
        countsPerA[a1 - MIN_MASS_NUMBER] += 1;

        int z1 = fissionProducts.at(1);
        countsPerZ[z1 - MIN_ATOMIC_NUMBER] += 1;

        int a2 = fissionProducts.at(2);
        countsPerA[a2 - MIN_MASS_NUMBER] += 1;

        int z2 = fissionProducts.at(3);
        countsPerA[z2 - MIN_ATOMIC_NUMBER] += 1;

        i++;

        double percentage = (100.0 * i)/nSim;
        printf("Progress: %d %%\r", static_cast<int>(percentage));
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    //here I pass countsPerA and countsPerZ to another function which plots results
}
```

Here are my results, out of 10000 repetitions of the experiment.

For Mass Numbers:
[image: Mass Number Products Frequencies]
For Atomic Numbers:
[image: Atomic Number Products Frequencies]

It is strange because with the same strategy, atomic numbers seems to be correctly simulated, while mass numbers definitely not. What am I doing wrong with mass numbers?

Comment: Interesting note: The mass number graph seems to be scaled up by 2 and *combined* with the Atomic Numbers graph, with the X axis scaled up by some factor. If you identify where the atomic number weights are affecting your mass generation, you can remove that interference, the other seems to be an issue of doubled scale.

Comment: From this observation i think the problem lies somewhere in your input data, and not necessarily in the generator function. Showing additional code relating to the initialization and especially the constructor function of your `IntegerRandomGenerator` may reveal something.

Comment: Unrelated: See if you can get that lonely `rand` out of there. [`rand` sucks](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and will be biasing the results a bit.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: I will edit my question accordingly to your comments

Comment: Sorry I missed an obvious bug. I don't know whether it is the source of the problem, but it might well be: You are creating a new random number generator instance in each call of `generate`. This is 1. definitely badly performing and 2. probably not going to create random data. Create only *one* `mt19937_64` instance in your program, seed it *once* and use only that instance later.

Comment: Other side notes: 1. Don't use macros to define constants, use variables instead: `const auto MIN_MASS_NUMBER = 66;`, etc. 2. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of raw arrays. 3. There is no need to use `memset` (there almost never is in C++ and it can go wrong very easily if you happen to be working with non-trivial types). Instead you can initialize arrays (or `std::array`) to zero directly using *value-initialization*: `int countsPerZ[ATOMIC_YIELD_LENGTH]{};` or using `std::fill`, which works similar to `memset` but is type-safe and works with any container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're populating the `countsPerA` and `countsPerZ` arrays:

```
    int a1 = fissionProducts.at(0);
    countsPerA[a1 - MIN_MASS_NUMBER] += 1;

    int z1 = fissionProducts.at(1);
    countsPerZ[z1 - MIN_ATOMIC_NUMBER] += 1;

    int a2 = fissionProducts.at(2);
    countsPerA[a2 - MIN_MASS_NUMBER] += 1;

    int z2 = fissionProducts.at(3);
    countsPerA[z2 - MIN_ATOMIC_NUMBER] += 1; //typo here
```

You're adding data from the atomic numbers results into the Mass Numbers count due to a typo.